# How to store data in matlab.net.http.ResponseMessage from GET request to file

Tags: matlab, http, get

I am trying to learn how to use the [Matlab http interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/http-interface.html). And I am hoping to download a few `.swf` files.

It seems Matlab is able to download the file as long as URL is valid following the Send HTTP Message [example in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.net.http.requestmessage.send.html#ref_q3fxxeg2m12-response) to the letter. And I say it seems the download works because `.ContentType` returns what is expected.

```
>> resp.Body.ContentType
ans = 
  MediaType with properties:

          Type: "application"
       Subtype: "x-shockwave-flash"
    Parameters: "["charset" "utf-8"]"
     MediaInfo: "application/x-shockwave-flash; charset=utf-8"
        Weight: []
```

But how do you store data to file when the data is not image or text? I can't find any documentation on that front. ([example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.net.http.messagebody-class.html))

---

EDIT:

My attempt.

I think the following passage from [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/http-matlab-data-type-conversion.html#bvdhh4e) applies:

> If MATLAB does not support the type, or if the
>   HTTPOptions.ConvertResponse property is set to false, then:
>
> - If the type is character-based, then Data contains the payload
>     converted to string.
> - Otherwise, Data contains the raw uint8 vector.

So I was going to naively try outputting the payload to text file and hope for the best. A few things first though.

```
>> class(resp.Body.Data)
ans =
    'string'

>> current = slCharacterEncoding()
current =
    'windows-1252'
```

I tried writing the data to text file without worrying about potential encoding problems. Needless to say, it doesn't work.

```
>> fid=fopen('out1.swf','wt');
>> fprintf(fid,'%s',resp.Body.Data);
>> fclose(fid);
```

The first line of the resulting file, when read in hex code, is

```
4357 5309 1a7e 0000 781a 1a1a 0938 1a1a
```

while the correct file, when downloading directly using Chrome and able to display the correct content, is

```
4357 5309 a5bc 0000 78da 7cbb 0934 d46f
```

Changing charset to utf-8 using `slCharacterEncoding` either doesn't work in this case or the encoding is still wrong. First line of file output as follows.

```
>> slCharacterEncoding('UTF-8');
>> resp = send(r,uri);
>> fid=fopen('out1.swf','w+');
>> fprintf(fid,'%s',resp.Body.Data);
>> fclose(fid);

4357 5309 efbf bd7e 0000 78ef bfbd efbf
```

(I know the files do not need to be identical to be read correctly. I visually inspected the output. I am only using the first line to demonstrate the mismatch.)

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about what a file is. Files are all stored in some text format, even images. If I got a jpeg file over HTTP and wanted to write that to a file, I would stream the response body into the file the same way as a text file and save it as a .jpg. The file type then constitutes how the text is processed by any other applications. Does that help at all?

Comment: I don't particularly care what format Matlab stores the data within the workspace. I need to know what that is (e.g. unicode 32) and also be able to export to hard drive. File in the hard drive is what I mean by file. I can edit the question.

Comment: On a second thought, I am going to leave the question as is. The intention seems clear to me as is. For anyone familiar with the package, Matlab has special handling for image and text files. What I said should not be misleading.